# Subquerying in MongoEngine

Tags: python, mongodb, mongoengine, nosql

Having the sample code:

```
import mongoengine as mongo

class User(mongo.Document):
    name = mongo.StringField()
    age = mongo.IntField()    

class Post(mongo.Document):
    title = mongo.StringField()
    author = mongo.ReferenceField(User)
```

I want to get all the posts created by users with ages below 30, one way is to make the request in two steps:

```
users = User.objects(age__lt=30)
posts = Post.objects(author__in=users)
```

But even this is not totally bad, it is calling and connecting to the database N times unnecessarily. So I want to make the query in just one step, I tried:

```
posts = Post.objects(author__age__lt=30)
```

But does not work, it just returns me a empty list, not an error. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

> What am I doing wrong?

Nothing you can't query across reference fields - see [Embed Vs Reference](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Schema+Design#SchemaDesign-Embedvs.Reference)

So even if the syntax was supported it would take two queries behind the scenes.  If its something thats wanted - add a ticket to github and I'll look into adding it :)

Updates to MongoEngine are coming in thick and fast at the moment - so a new release will be coming soon!  Some exciting improvements are on the [dev](https://github.com/hmarr/mongoengine/tree/dev) branch, including efficient lazy dereferencing and update deltas for atomic saving!

Comment: Ross is this available yet in MongoEngine? Would definitely be useful. Thanks.

Comment: Theres no ticket for it, I'm not sure its wise to implement as it covers too much of the internals.

Comment: Ok, it's no big deal. It's not really an impediment, just a convenience. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> ... it is calling and connecting to the database N times unnecessarily

MongoDB supports an `$in` clause that allows for the selection of multiple objects with only one query, one connection. If you're seeing multiple connections, you should probably report this to the author of mongoengine.

Because MongoDB does not support joins, your method of *"load users, load their posts"* is generally the correct method.

> What am I doing wrong?

For this level of detail, your best bet is to [contact the author directly](https://github.com/hmarr/). The github page has both his e-mail and his blog. Looking at the repo, his last update was October 2010 and the last version number was 0.4. Three months with no update is a long time in this space and he doesn't even have a 1.0 version, so it's quite likely that you'll need to speak with the author directly.